# Using cut to return the middle of a string

Tags: bash, shell, string, cut

I have an xml string echoed to `stdout` along the lines of

```
<xml:attribute>{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}</xml:attribute>
```

I want to return the string `{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}` in this case. I was thinking of using cut (maybe even piping it twice) but I have no idea the proper syntax. I'm using bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut`'s `-d` option to define a delimiter (which is excluded from the resulting fields):

```
echo "<xml:attribute>{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}</xml:attribute>" | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1
```

This splits on `>` and outputs the second field, leaving `{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}</xml:attribute`, then again on `<` and outputs the first field.

Fields describe the text in between delimiters, and between the start of the text and the first delimiter, and the last delimiter and the end of the text. Using `>` on the original text, you end up with:

1. `<xml:attribute`
2. `{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}</xml:attribute`
3. the empty string

(the delimiter is ommitted). Then using `<` on field 2 gives

1. `{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}`
2. `/xml:attribute`

and field 1 there is the result you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect, it works but I am still a little unsure about the 'fields'..

Answer (score 1):

For simple string manipulations, you should generally use the shell's own constructs, tied to [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). External utilities are better at processing large volumes of text, but for a single string, launching an external tool is slow and getting the quoting right can be difficult.

```
mystring='<xml:attribute>{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}</xml:attribute>'
content="${mystring#*>}"; content="${content%<*}"
braced="${mystring#*\{}"; braced="${braced%%\}*}"; braced="{$braced}"
```

`content` is set to the original string minus the leading and trailing `<…>` parts. `braced` is set to the first part that looks like `{…}`.

Comment: Indeed, with the caveat that the shell's string operators take a while to get used to, and many users find them hard to read (so for example in some professional settings I'd use `cut` because the resulting script will be easier to maintain by the people who have to maintain it after me).

Comment: @StephenKitt also the inline substitution is more fragile/dangerous unless someone has magic error handling. use, but use wisely. the "getting the quoting right" is also more a case of 'what you know best' and not of "A is harder than B".

Answer (score 1):

You can also have `sed` extract the field specified by a regular expression. Useful if you have more complex matching criteria:

```
echo '<xml:attribute>{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}</xml:attribute>' | \
sed -E 's/^.+>({.+})<.+$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with `awk`, using the regexp `<|>` as the field delimiter:

```
$ echo "<xml:attribute>{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}</xml:attribute>" | 
       awk -F '<|>' '{print $3}'
{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}
```

Note: tested with GNU `awk`, `mawk`, and `original-awk`.  Works the same in all three.

The `perl` version is very similar (except `perl` arrays are zero-based, and `perl`'s `print` statement doesn't output a trailing `\n` unless you explicitly tell it to):

```
echo "<xml:attribute>{41c33a-4893b-3627a-617a}</xml:attribute>" |
     perl -n -a -F'<|>' -e 'print $F[2],"\n"'
```

Also note - this only works reliably because it's a single line of input containing a single fragment of XML.  Regular expressions can't be used to reliably parse actual XML.  Use an XML parsing tool instead for that, e.g. `xmlstarlet` or one of the many XML-parsing libraries for `perl`, `python`, and other languages.